# SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_USE_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_FOR_DB_CREDENTIALS Not working for scheduled jobs in SCDF

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to mask the DB credentials for the task I schedule from SCDF. I'm using the version 2.6.1. The SCDF and Tasks run in Openshift platform.

When I launch a job for a single execution with the property `SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_USE_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_FOR_DB_CREDENTIALS=true` (added to SCDF-deployment.yaml) without any schedule, the DB Credentials are masked in POD description page. But when I schedule the same job from SCDF then the DB credentials are exposed even though the same property is still set to true.

I'm looking for any additional configurations or workarounds to mask the DB Credentials even when the jobs are launched by schedules from SCDF. Currently it's working only for non-scheduled jobs/tasks.

Below are the changes I made to mask the crendentials.

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scdf-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scdf-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: scdf-server
        image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/batch/scdf-server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/info
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1.0
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 512Mi
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: dev
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
        - name: SERVER_PORT
          value: '80'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_ANALYTICS_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_COMPOSED_TASK_RUNNER_URI
          value: 'docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:2.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_ENABLE_API
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_ENABLE_API
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_PATHS
          value: /etc/secrets
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_TASKS_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_NAME
          value: scdf-server
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI
          value: 'http://${SCDF_SERVER_SERVICE_HOST}:${SCDF_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT}'
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          value: "{ \"maven\": { \"local-repository\": null, \"remote-repositories\": { \"repo1\": { \"url\": \"https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot\"} } } }"
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_USE_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_FOR_DB_CREDENTIALS
          value: 'true'
      serviceAccountName: scdf-sa
```

Comment: You are correct.   There is an github issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3985

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Could you tell me in which release the fix would be available ?

Comment: Will have a PR for the issue #3985 today.   So it will be in 2.7.   I'll check to see if we want to backport to 2.6.x